# recv() goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I am trying to send a file 4 bytes at a time , if the length of the contents of the file is not divisible by 4 i add some extra space and the i send it

When i send some string it's working but for some string  recv() is going into infinite loop

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

int ssock , csock ; 
struct sockaddr_in server ;

server.sin_family = AF_INET ; 
server.sin_port = htons(8088);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


ssock = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (ssock == -1 ) {
                cout << " Error " ; return 0 ;
        }

connect(ssock , (sockaddr *)&server ,sizeof(server));
/*void *buff ; 
int len = recv(ssock , buff ,1024,0 );
int  *ptr =  (int *)buff ;
cout << *ptr ;*/
void * buff ;
int len;
while(len = recv(ssock , buff ,4,0 )){
        cout<<(char *)buff<<len<<"\n";


}


  return 0 ;
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

int ssock , csock ; 
struct sockaddr_in server ;

server.sin_family = AF_INET ; 
server.sin_port = htons(8088);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


ssock = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (ssock == -1 ) {
                cout << " Error " ; return 0 ;
        }

bind(ssock , (sockaddr *)&server ,sizeof(server));
listen(ssock,5);
socklen_t size  = sizeof (server );
fstream fin("text.txt",ios::in);
string s((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)),istreambuf_iterator<char>());
fin.close();
//cout<<s;
int len = s.size();
if(len % 4 != 0 ) {
        s.pop_back();
        int i = len % 4 ;
        i =  4 - i ;
        while(i){s.push_back(' ');i--;}
        s.push_back('\0');
}
cout<<s<<"\n"<<s.size()<<"\n";

while(csock = accept(ssock,(sockaddr *)&server ,&size)){

        cout<<"\n Connection Accpeted \n" ;
        /*int s = 172;
        send(csock , (void *)&s, sizeof(s),0);*/
       int i = 0;

        i = 0 ;
        while(i <= s.size()){
        string temp =s.substr(i,4);
        cout<<temp<<"\n";
        cout<<send(csock,(void *)temp.c_str() ,4,0);
        i+=4;
        }

        close(csock);





}

  return 0 ;
}
```

Is there any issues while sending or while receiving , kinda stuck at this point for sometime .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.  See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to bring your question up to standards.

Answer (score 2):

```
void * buff ;
int len;
while(len = recv(ssock , buff ,4,0 )){
    cout<<(char *)buff<<len<<"\n";
}
```

There are at least three bugs here:

1. You're passing the value of `buff` to `recv`, but you haven't set any value. So you're passing garbage.
2. When you pass a `char *` to `cout`, it has to be a C-style string. You can't use it to print arbitrary data you've received from a connection. For one thing, how would it know how many bytes to print?
3. You don't handle negative values returned by `recv`.

Answer (score 0):

check the return value of recv for -ve values. you'll miss any errors otherwise.

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.